# Given a list of shift start times, how do you determine which range a particular hour belongs to?

Tags: python, algorithm, date, datetime, time

I am given a list of shift starting hour: [1, 4, 9, 13, 17, 21]

This means that:

1. the first person is responsible from 1:00 to 3:59
2. the second person is responsible from 4:00 to 8:59
3. ...
4. the last person is responsible from 21:00 to 01:00

### Given a datetime, how can I get the starting datetime of the last shift?

Examples:

- for March 14th 12:49, it should return March 14th 9:00
- for March 14th 23:59, it should return March 14th 21:00
- for March 15th 00:30, it should return March 14th 21:00.

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: This can be done simply by searching for the nearest starting point that is less than or equalled to the time, for the time range that from [21:00 , 1:00], just break it into two ranges [21:00, 23:59], [0:00, 1:00]. Either a binary search tree or binary search can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it -

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime as dt
dt_str = 'March 15th 00:30'
dt_given = dt.strptime(dt_str, '%B %dth %H:%M')
L = [1, 4, 9, 13, 17, 21]

round_hr = dt_given.replace(hour=0, minute=0)
def get_shift(L, dt_given):
    try:
        return dt_given.replace(hour=max( [ i for i in L if dt_given > dt_given.replace(hour=i, minute=0) ] ), minute=0)
    except ValueError:
        return (dt_given - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=max(L), minute=0)

shift = get_shift(L, dt_given)
print(dt.strftime(shift, '%B %dth %H:%M'))
```

**Output**

```
March 14th 21:00
```

**Breakdown**

```
[ i for i in L if dt_given > dt_given.replace(hour=i, minute=0) ]
```

This piece converts all the `hours` in `L` to corresponding dates of the same day and then compares and retrieves all dates that are less than the target date. The `max()` on top of that gives the immediate shift.

The problem starts with the previous day/next day. In your `or March 15th 00:30` example, it fails because there is no shift date on the same day. In this situation, there is a `catch` which simply subtracts a day and gets the latest shift from there.

```
except ValueError:
        return (dt_given - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=max(L), minute=0)
```

I am not sure what boundary/edge cases I might be missing, but I am all ears.

Comment: Very nicely done! Your solution is both terse and direct. To be frank, I was hoping that there will be some Python library that will allow me to do this easily but your solution is elegant enough!